# Problems with a wms layer in Openlayers 3

Tags: wms, openlayers

First of all sorry if my English isn't good.

I'm trying to add a layer into an OpenLayers 3 map. This one is which I want to insert:

```
new ol.layer.Image({
    name: 'cartografia',
    style: 'cartografia',
    visible: true, 
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'http://www.geo.euskadi.net/arcgis/services/U11_AGS_WMS_Cartografia/MapServer/WMSServer?', 
        params: { 
            'LAYERS': '1',
            'STYLES': 'default' 
        },
        serverType: 'geoserver' }) })
```

When I go to http://www.geo.euskadi.net/arcgis/services/U11_AGS_WMS_Cartografia/MapServer/WMSServer?request=getcapabilities into the browser, I can see the xml, but I'm not able to insert the layer

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's a ArcGIS Server and not Geoserver that delivers the WMS.

( See http://www.geo.euskadi.net/arcgis/rest/services )

so this should work:

```
new ol.layer.Image({
         source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: 'http://www.geo.euskadi.net/arcgis/services/U11_AGS_WMS_Cartografia/MapServer/WMSServer?',
             ratio: 1,
             params: {
                 'LAYERS': '1',
                     'TRANSPARENT': 'true'
             }
         })
     });
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/njnf55fp/

Answer (score 0):

The Server Software providing the WMS is ArcGIS and not GeoServer, the `ol.source.wms.ServerType` parameter is used when the server software adds additional (vendor specific) capabilities, but ArcGIS doesn't do this, so this parameter should be omitted.

Allowed values are currently:

```
'carmentaserver', 'geoserver', 'mapserver', 'qgis'
```

So the following should work:

```
new ol.layer.Image({
  name: 'cartografia',
  style: 'cartografia',
  visible: true, 
  source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
    url: 'http://www.geo.euskadi.net/arcgis/services/U11_AGS_WMS_Cartografia/MapServer/WMSServer?', 
    params: { 
        'LAYERS': '1',
        'STYLES': 'default'}
    }) 
});
```

Another issue may be the projection you are using, the layer in the WMS service you are [calling](http://www.geo.euskadi.eus/arcgis/services/U11_AGS_WMS_Cartografia/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS&) only supports the following CRS:

```
<Layer>
  <Name>1</Name>
  <Title>Itzalak / Sombras MDT LIDAR 2012 5000</Title>
  <Abstract>Itzalak / Sombras MDT LIDAR 2012 5000</Abstract>    
  <CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
  <CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
  <CRS>EPSG:23030</CRS>
  <CRS>EPSG:25830</CRS>
  <EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
   <westBoundLongitude>-3.457379</westBoundLongitude>
   <eastBoundLongitude>-1.683561</eastBoundLongitude> 
   <southBoundLatitude>42.463020</southBoundLatitude>
   <northBoundLatitude>43.457532</northBoundLatitude>
  </EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
```